# google.maps.event.addListenerOnce Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi so I have a draggable, editable rectangle object here:

```
rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: bounds,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
});
```

Then I have two listeners for rectangle:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'mouseup', function () {
    foo2()
});
```

The first listener calls foo1() which does not require much processing, and is required to run every time 'bounds_changed' occurs.

The second listener calls foo2() when there is a 'mouseup' event on the rectangle(I use this mouse up as a 'dragend').
I also want foo2() to be called when 'bounds_changed' occurs since the rectangle is editable by the user. However foo2() requires a lot of processing so I only want it called at the end of 'bounds_changed'.

I've tried adding the listener once:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(rectangle, 'bounds_changed', function () {
   foo2();
});
```

But this only works one time.

Comment: Can't you just use `addListener` on the `dragend` event to fire `foo2()`?

Comment: Omg I'm an idiot.. I was reading the rectangle API for evens and dragend wasn't there.. Cheers it works.